# Ruby, Linearize an array with a sorted number series by adding items in order to keep the differentials lower or equal to X

Tags: ruby

I need a function that transforms an array of integers in descending order, not allowing any integer in position i to be X times greater than the following in position i+1, by adding 1 or more elements in between, and keeping the original numbers intact.

The resulting sorted array will meet the criteria:

```
array[i] <= array[i+1]*1.5
```

For every i.

Examples:

```
x = 1.5
```

Transformation over a

```
a = [5, 3]
func(a, x) = [5,4,3]

a[0] > a[1]*1.5, so func adds 4 = (a[0].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts a
a is now [5,4,3]
```

Transformation over b

```
b = [50, 4]
func(b, x) = [50, 34, 23, 16, 11, 8, 6, 4]

b[0] > b[1]*1.5, so func adds 34 = (b[0].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts b
b is now [50,34,4]

b[1] > b[2]*1.5, so func adds 23 = (b[1].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts b
b is now [50,34,23,4]

b[2] > b[3]*1.5, so func adds 16 = (b[2].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts b
b is now [50,34,23,16,4]

b[3] > b[4]*1.5, so func adds 11 = (b[3].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts b
b is now [50,34,23,16,11,4]

b[4] > b[5]*1.5, so func adds 8 = (b[4].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts b
b is now [50,34,23,16,11,8,4]

b[5] > b[6]*1.5, so func adds 6 = (b[5].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts b
b is now [50,34,23,16,11,8,4]

func returns [50, 34, 23, 16, 11, 8, 6, 4]
```

Transformation over c

```
c = [50, 20, 10, 4, 3, 2]
func(c, x) = [50, 34, 23, 20, 14, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2]

c[0] > c[1]*1.5, so func adds 34 = (c[0].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts c
c is now [50,34,20,10,4,3,2]

c[1] > c[2]*1.5, so func adds 23 = (c[1].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts c
c is now [50,34,23,20,10,4,3,2]

c[3] > c[4]*1.5, so func adds 14 = (c[3].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts c
c is now [50,34,23,20,14,10,4,3,2]

c[5] > c[6]*1.5, so func adds 7 = (c[5].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts c
c is now [50,34,23,20,14,10,7,4,3,2]

c[6] > c[7]*1.5, so func adds 5 = (c[6].to_f/1.5).ceil and sorts c
c is now [50,34,23,20,14,10,7,5,4,3,2]

func returns [50, 34, 23, 20, 14, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

How can this be done in a functional and clean way?

Comment: `(23 / 1.5).ceil` is 16, not 15. Could you check your output for the second example again?

Comment: sorry about that. changed it! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure functional way:

```
def func(a, x, i = 0)
  if i == a.size - 1
    a
  else
    if a[i] <= a[i + 1] * x
      func a, x, i + 1
    else
      func a.take(i + 1) + [(a[i].to_f / x).ceil] + a.drop(i + 1), x, i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting the exact same output as your first and third examples, but not for the second -- your sample output seems to be incorrect.

Test:

```
p func [5, 3], 1.5
p func [50, 4], 1.5
p func [50, 20, 10, 4, 3, 2], 1.5
```

Output:

```
[5, 4, 3]
[50, 34, 23, 16, 11, 8, 6, 4]
[50, 34, 23, 20, 14, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Very cool. It should be noted that this will produce an infinite loop for x = 1, right ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful. It divides intervals geometrically so that each subdivision has (as near as is possible) the same multiplier as the others, instead of using 1.5 for all but the last and then whatever's left over.

```
include Math

def geometric_interpolation(arr, ratio)

  log_ratio = log(ratio)
  result = []

  arr.each_cons(2) do |pair|
    logs = pair.map { |x| log(x) }
    log_interval = logs[0] - logs[1]
    num = (log_interval / log_ratio).round(12).ceil
    result += [ pair[0] ] + (1...num).map { |n| exp(logs[0] - log_interval * n / num).round }
  end

  result + [ arr[-1] ]

end

a = [5, 3]
b = [50, 4]
c = [50, 20, 10, 4, 3, 2]

p geometric_interpolation(a, 1.5)
p geometric_interpolation(b, 1.5)
p geometric_interpolation(c, 1.5)
```

**output**

```
[5, 4, 3]
[50, 35, 24, 17, 12, 8, 6, 4]
[50, 37, 27, 20, 14, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```